# Redirect subfolder to root with nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I’ve moved my wordpress site from example.com/mobile to example.com.

For this work, I want:

1. example.com/mobile not redirect. I want it not redirect because I
   have a category with mobile slug on example.com.
2. example.com/mobile/anycharacter redirect to example.com/anycharacter

This is my nginx rule:

```
location ~ ^/mobile/ {
   rewrite ^/mobile/(.*?)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This worked with:

- example.com/mobile redirect example.com
- example.com/mobile/anycharacter redirect to example.com/anycharacter

Anyone have suggest to help me solve this problem (not redirect example.com/mobile to example.com)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/mobile(/.+) $1 permanent;` at the server context. Do not use a dedicated location for such a rewrite rule.

Comment: Thank you. It's work like my rule. 

But i want example.com/mobile/anycharacter redirect to example.com/anycharacter but example.com/mobile not redirect to example.com.

Have you got any suggest?

Comment: Used regex pattern does not match `/mobile` or `/mobile/` exact URIs. Most likely you got a previous redirect cached by your browser. Clear your browser cache or try it from the incognito browser window.

Comment: I've try location = /mobile from [this guide](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) but it not work (still redirect example.com/mobile to example.com). Can you help me write right rule for this problem? Thank you very much!

`location = /mobile {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location = /mobile/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location /mobile/ {
   rewrite ^/mobile/(.*?)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}`

Comment: Did you understand my previous answer? The rule I suggested should work as expected being placed directly at the server block without any additional locations. If it isn't, most likely redirect is coming from your browser cache or some intermediate proxy server cache, if any. Maybe you didn't remove your previous `location ~ ^/mobile/ { ... }` or didn't reload nginx after making configuration changes. Additionally you can check what actually happens using `curl` command line utility. I don't know how I can help any further, the rewrite rule __should__ work as expected.